# Process function in parallel/async and append results, returning one list of results?

Tags: f#, html-agility-pack, c#-to-f#

I have a function that returns a string[].

```
let asyncScrape url allParameters =
    allParameters
    |> Seq.map(fun v ->
        yearAndClassResultsAsync url v)
        |> Async.Parallel
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

I want to iterate through that string array, sending each string to a method called resultsBody (that returns a seq), and then finally returning an single sequence that is the concatenation of the results from resultsBody.

I tried doing something like below, but I'm rather lost as it returns:

```
seq<string[]>[]
```

and I just want a single combined

```
seq<string[]>
```

My attempts so far:

```
let parseSite html =
    Array.mapi (fun s -> resultsBody) html
```

Comment: This question would be a lot easier to answer if you provided a minimal example of your problem.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam updated original question with minimal example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified, I think your problem is that you have a nested sequence of `string`s and you want to get as much parallelism as possible, rather than just at the innermost layer of the nesting.

One way you can do this is to also nest the `Async.Parallel` calls before calling `Async.RunSynchronously`. Here's a simple example of the technique:

```
let squareInt n = async { return n*n }

let inParallel (seqOfseqOfInts : seq<seq<int>>) =
    seqOfseqOfInts
        |> Seq.map        // deal with each inner seq of ints
            (fun (seqOfInts : seq<int>) ->
                seqOfInts
                    |> Seq.map squareInt
                    |> Async.Parallel // this gives us Async<int[]>
            ) // this gives us seq<Async<int[]>>
        |> Async.Parallel // this gives us Async<int[][]>
        |> Async.RunSynchronously // this gives us int[][]
```

Comment: I updated my original post with more clear/concise information, as I do have it running async but just can't get the data type that I want.

Comment: Have you tried my answer but with three levels of Async.Parallel?